# django-summernote setting configuration failing only language part

Tags: python, django, summernote

summernote and inside setting, I want to change language setting that I followed the documentation. According to the [documentation](https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote), I just need to do:

```
SUMMERNOTE_CONFIG = {
    # Or, set editor language/locale forcely
    'lang': 'ko-KR',
}
```

I tried other settings and they work fine, but only language one isn't working. Is this because I already am using locale for other app? Or am I configuring it wrong?

Comment: What are the symptoms? Have you followed the steps described here: http://summernote.org/getting-started/#i18n-support?

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out by removing `lang:None`, you must be putting this in summer note config somewhere